# How to modify the table contents after receiving it from the API in the context of Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js

I am displaying table by using REST API, so in my API response few data in objects contains null data and few data contains negative values, here below is my response that i am getting:

I have shown only two response for better understanding.

```
{
  "id": 778,
  "date": "12/12/12",
  "low": 175,
  "high": 176,
  "per_low": 78,
  "per_high": 89,
  "gets": "180",
  "loss": 16,
  "ease": "ok",
  "status": "Closed",
  "challenge": -0.41  // Whenever it is negative i want to display it with red color text.
},
{
  "id": 779,
  "date": "2/8/13",
  "low": 135,
  "high": 186,
  "per_low": 58,
  "per_high": 99,
  "gets": null, // Whenever it is null i want to display '-'
  "loss": 6,
  "ease": "ok",
  "status": "Closed",
  "challenge": 2.41   // Whenever it is positive i want to display it with green color text
}
```

As you can see my response, i am looking to modify some of the inputs coming from the API when the response is successful, so below i have shown how i tried it:

```
<template>

  <div id="ag-grid-demo">
    <vx-card>

      <!-- TABLE ACTION ROW -->
      <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center">

        <!-- ITEMS PER PAGE -->
        <div class="mb-4 md:mb-0 mr-4 ag-grid-table-actions-left">
          <vs-dropdown vs-trigger-click class="cursor-pointer">
            <div class="p-4 border border-solid d-theme-border-grey-light rounded-full d-theme-dark-bg cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-between font-medium">
              <span class="mr-2">{{ currentPage * paginationPageSize - (paginationPageSize - 1) }} - {{ robot.length - currentPage * paginationPageSize > 0 ? currentPage * paginationPageSize : robot.length }} of {{ robot.length }}</span>
              <feather-icon icon="ChevronDownIcon" svgClasses="h-4 w-4" />
            </div>
          </vs-dropdown>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ag-grid-vue
        ref="agGridTable"
        :gridOptions="gridOptions"
        class="ag-theme-material w-100 my-4 ag-grid-table"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
        :rowData="robot"
        rowSelection="multiple"
        colResizeDefault="shift"
        :animateRows="true"
        :floatingFilter="true"
        :pagination="true"
        :paginationPageSize="paginationPageSize"
        :suppressPaginationPanel="true"
        :enableRtl="$vs.rtl">
      </ag-grid-vue>
      <vs-pagination
        :total="totalPages"
        :max="maxPageNumbers"
        v-model="currentPage" />
    </vx-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data () {
   return {
         columnDefs: [
  {
    headerName: 'Date ',
    field: 'date',
    width: 200,
    filter: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Low',
    field: 'low',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'High',
    field: 'high',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Per Low',
    field: 'per_low',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Per High',
    field: 'per_high',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Gets',
    field: 'gets',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Loss',
    field: 'loss',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Ease',
    field: 'ease',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Status',
    field: 'status',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Challenge',
    field: 'challenge',
    filter: true,
    width: 200
  }
], robot: [],
 }
   },


   methods: {
        table(id, value) {
          this.$http.get(`/database/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
              this[value] = response.data
              if (this[value].gets === null ){
                this[value].gets = '-'
              } else{
                this[value].gets
              }
              if (this[value].challenge >= 0) {
                this[value].challenge = ' class=\'positive\''
              } else {
                this[value].challenge = ' class=\'negative\''
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }
      },
      mounted () {
          this.table(8, 'robot')
      }
    }
     </script>
```

As you can see my code, i have tried to modify the data coming from the API, But only the data which is coming from API is displayed in my table. No modifications are reflecting in my table. (if statement are not reflecting)

Please someone help me with this, i want to know is this the right way to do it. And what changes should i do in order make it reflect on my table.

Objective: I want to display '-', whenever the "gets" data displays null, and i want display green color text whenever the "challenge" display positive value and red color text whenever the "challenge" display negative value.

Comment: can you share html template

Comment: Can you please see my code, i have updated it!

Comment: ok.. you are using ag-grid.. can you please also share `columnDefs`, i will tell you what to do

Comment: I have updated my code please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify data, rather use ag-grid apis to apply custom styles, class or format data. Please note i have no tested it but it should work.

1. simply assign data to `robot`, do not make any changes to the data.

```
table(id, value) {
    this.$http.get(`/database/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
              this.robot = response.data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error)
            })
}
```

2. Add columnDefs for `gets` and `challenge` cols like this

```
columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Gets',
        field: 'gets',
        filter: true,
        width: 200,
        valueFormatter: function(params){
           return params.value ? params.value : '-'
        }
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Challenge',
        field: 'challenge',
        filter: true,
        width: 200,
        valueFormatter: function(params){
           return params.value ? (params.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + params.value + '%' : ''
        },
        cellStyle: function(params) {
          if (parseInt(params.value) >0 ) {
             return { color: 'green'};
          } else {
             return { color: 'red'};
        }
      }
  ]
```

Comment: I should change this in the columnDefs right. But why have you used this.columnDefs or u meant to change it in .then ??

Comment: yup...just update columnDefs for 2 columns- gets and challenge

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try it, and let you know.

Comment: and remove code modification you did in `then`, not needed. simply return data.

Comment: Welcome. glad i could help you.

Comment: Hello @Nilesh Patel, I wanted to append '%' to my columndefs how can I do that ?

Comment: say, i have a column -name, you want to display name suffix by '%'??

Comment: Yes, for example, if my API returns positive 17 I want to display it as +17%, if my API returns negative 17 I want to display it as -17%

Comment: Can you please show in the Challenge header in the answer you sent me.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nilesh Patel i got it!

Comment: Hello @Nilesh Patel, hope your fine, can you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933419/vuejs-unable-to-catch-the-axios-error-in-vue-cli-project

Comment: Hello @Nilesh, i had small doubt regarding the columnDefs, as you can see my question above few headerName are given as Per Low and Per High, i want to display it in two different lines like Per above and below that low (newline ). I tried something \n and </br> both did not work out. Please do help me.

Comment: And also, as you can see my question above i have used fixed width for every columnDefs, i just want it to adapt the screen width and display all the culumns, please do help me how i can do it.