# VueJS - How to automatically close popup after receiving success message

Tags: vue.js, popup

I am using vs-popup component of Vusax library to display contents, I am able to close the vs-popup by a method which is in the code below. I am actually having a form inside the popup, So my question is how to make the vs-popup close automatically after success message.

Here is the User.vue

**HTML**

```
 <vs-button @click="popupSettings = true" > Settings</vs-button>

<vs-popup title="Settings"  :active.sync="popupSettings ">
    <user-settings>
        <vs-button color="dark" @click="close()">Cancel</vs-button>    //This is the slot
    </user-settings>
</vs-popup>
```

**JS**

```
 close () {
      return this.popupSettings  = false
    },
```

Here is the UserSettings.vue

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <slot></slot>
  <vs-button  @click="saveSettings($event)" >Save</vs-button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
      this.$http.put(/settings, params)
      .then((response) => {
        this.alert('success', 'Success', 'Settings saved successfully!')

        // Here i want to close the vs-popup but that is in User.vue
      })
```

Please do help me, how i can do this.

Comment: You could emit an event from `UserSettings.vue` to the parent withing your `.then`, watch this event on the parent and call `close()` there. A more ugly solution would be to use `$parent` and some `$refs` to trigger `close()` on it.

Comment: Can you please, show it in my code, because i wanna know where i am going wrong

Comment: I got it thank you so much

Comment: I've written an answer to show you how to do it (took me some time to reproduce your use case). I'm not sure if it's okay in the way I did or if you **really** need to pass a slot here, in which case you can use scoped-slots, tell me and I'll show you an example on this one (a bit more advanced).

Comment: Thanks a lot, like i understood whatever you said me for the first time and i implemented and i got it similar to the answer you sent me. So scope slots are not required here. Then do you have any idea of ag-grid table ?

Comment: Not sure to understand: do you have another question on `ag-grid` ? It's maybe using scoped-slots indeed.

Comment: It is not at all related to scoped slots. This is completely different question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536098/how-to-modify-the-table-contents-after-receiving-it-from-the-api-in-the-context , this is the link of the question, i just had one doubt in this question, ie i have used columnDefs data function where u can see i have used Per low, so i want to display it as a Per in first line and low in second line (i mean i want use new line after Per) i tried Per \n low did not workout and also tried Per </br> low did not work.

Comment: Not a pro and this question already got an answer, so maybe post another question. :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66010887/vuejs-how-to-have-a-custom-headername-of-columndefs-in-ag-grid-vue here is the question please tell how it can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of my above comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-firefly-frfkc?file=/src/App.vue

The interesting part in the children is here

```js
async saveSettings() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    if (json) this.$emit("success", true); // emit to the parent
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn("error", err);
  }
},
```

I've mocked some `GET` call, but you can handle it the same way with your `PUT`. I've used `async/await` for a more modern approach too and still getting some error feedback in case something bad happens.

---

In the parent, watch for the event and close the popup.

```html
<user-settings @success="closePopup">
  ...
</user-settings>
```

The event should be emitted only if the AJAX call is successful.