# VueJS - How to have a custom headerName of columnDefs in ag-grid-vue

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I am trying to display my header name in a new line, but i am unable to do it.

Version of ag-grid-vue: 6.12.0

Here is what i tried but it did not work out:

```
defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        editable: true,
        resizable: true,
        suppressMenu: true
      },
columnDefs: [
  {
    headerName: 'Average low ',  // This value is displayed in a single line
    field: 'average_low',
    width: 200,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Average high ', // Even this value is displayed in a single line
    field: 'average_high',
    width: 200,
  },
...
}
```

I tried something like this to display the headerName in new line:

```
      {
        headerName: 'Avg. \n low ',  // This value is displayed in a single line
        field: 'average_low',
        width: 200,
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Avg. </br> high ', // Even this value is displayed in a single line
        field: 'average_high',
        width: 200,
      },
```

I want to display something like this:

[image]

Please tell me how i can do this. Here is the officially documentation:

https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/vue/component-header/

and here is the plunker which shows the example and can be used to workout:

https://plnkr.co/edit/QGopxrvIoTPu2vkZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: here is a working solution >> https://plnkr.co/edit/Lr6cneCFiT91lCOD
Adapt it to your liking with the according theme (`alpine`, `balham` and so on) and the height that you wish or any other CSS structure that you have.
As told below, this inspired by [this guy's work](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2361#issuecomment-437885591).

A working solution can be done with the script below

```js
const MIN_HEIGHT = 80; // this line is the one you're looking for ! 

function autosizeHeaders(event) {
    if (event.finished !== false) {
        event.api.setHeaderHeight(MIN_HEIGHT);
        const headerCells = document.querySelectorAll('#myGrid .ag-header-cell-label');
        let minHeight = MIN_HEIGHT;
        headerCells.forEach(cell => {
            minHeight = Math.max(minHeight, cell.scrollHeight);
        });
        event.api.setHeaderHeight(minHeight);
    }
}

(function() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
        var gridOptions = {
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            onColumnResized: autosizeHeaders,
            onGridReady: autosizeHeaders,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    headerName: 'Header with a very long description',
                    field: 'name',
                    headerClass: 'multiline'
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Another long header title',
                    field: 'role',
                    headerClass: 'multiline'
                }
            ],
            rowData: [
                {name: 'Niall', role: 'Developer'},
                {name: 'Eamon', role: 'Manager'},
                {name: 'Brian', role: 'Musician'},
                {name: 'Kevin', role: 'Manager'}
            ]
        };
        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
    });
})();
```

There is a github issue [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2361) with a Stackoverflow thread with a lot of hacky (but working) solutions. It looks like there is no official support for this, so your best bet would be to check there and try out the various CSS solutions.

If you have a hosted example that we can play with, I may help more but right now, I can only recommend reading the various comments and try to tinker the CSS with your dev tools ! :)

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/vue/column-definitions/ here you can find out the example, please could you try, i tried various other ways but did not work out

Comment: The linked project is empty

Comment: If you go below that page you can find out the example, there you can actually work out with plunker, this is the link https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/vue/column-definitions/

Comment: Not really what I'd call a friendly way of debugging. Host it in codesandbox, it will be closer to what you will have too.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QGopxrvIoTPu2vkZ this is in vue

Comment: Hm, not really what I'd call in vue but alright. What did you tried so far ? Could you please update your question with the things you've tried so far ?

Comment: Thank you @kissu but, as mentioned in my question i just want to display the Avg. low and Avg. high as the image format

Comment: The hard part is done, if you want it to fit in a smaller width, go `.ag-header-cell-text { width: 4rem; }` and it will shrink. Ofc, you can make it dynamic with some JS logic depending of the length of your whole string.

Comment: Hello @kissu, i am getting just ... after certain width rather than going to a new line

Comment: Yeah, you basically don't need to "cut" it too early, the `...` are CSS ellipsis (because the given width cannot fit the word in it's whole). Try to tinker a bit and inspect the whole with your devtools. The newline is achieved by the script above.

Comment: Currently, i am using material theme, those styles are not working, i changed according to material theme, based on width it shows header...

Comment: Open a new question and ask for this specific case with the **EXACT** structure that you do have (not a _plnkr_). https://codesandbox.io will help you achieve getting something real that I can help you with. Take the time to format your question by doing this and it will be faster for everybody. to help :D Here it's essentially a CSS issue, nothing related to vue, that means that the structure is important.